# Which regular expression operator means 'Don't' match this character?

Tags: regex

`*, ?, +` characters all mean match this character. Which character means 'don't' match this? Examples would help.

Comment: For solution relating to not matching a word - See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can use negated character classes to exclude certain characters: for example `[^abcde]` will match anything but a,b,c,d,e characters.

Instead of specifying all the characters literally, you can use **shorthands** inside character classes: `[\w]` (lowercase) will match any "word character" (letter, numbers and underscore), `[\W]` (uppercase) will match anything but word characters; similarly, `[\d]` will match the  0-9 digits while `[\D]` matches anything but the 0-9 digits, and so on.

If you use PHP you can take a look at the [regex character classes documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php).

Comment: Any way to do this without using negated character classes?  I dislike having to use an entire class when it is just for one character.

Comment: @Cole - you've probably long-since figured this out, but for the next person, to negate a single letter, you would just use that in place of the character class.  e.g. `[^S]` would match anything that isn't an uppercase `S`.  It's clumsy, but there it is.

Answer (score 121):

There's two ways to say "don't match": character ranges, and zero-width negative lookahead/lookbehind.

The former: don't match `a`, `b`, `c` or `0`: `[^a-c0]`

The latter: match any three-letter string except `foo` and `bar`:

`(?!foo|bar).{3}`

or

`.{3}(?<!foo|bar)`

Also, a correction for you: `*`, `?` and `+` do not actually match anything. They are repetition operators, and always follow a matching operator. Thus, `a+` means match one or more of `a`, `[a-c0]+` means match one or more of `a`, `b`, `c` or `0`, while `[^a-c0]+` would match one or more of anything that wasn't `a`, `b`, `c` or `0`.

Comment: `^((?!foo).)+$` Match any line not containing foo
https://regex101.com/r/z6a65l/4/

Answer (score 68):

`[^]`  ( within **[ ]** ) is negation in regular expression whereas `^` is "begining of string"

`[^a-z]`  matches any single character that is **not** from "a" to "z"

`^[a-z]` means string starts with from "a" to "z"

[**Reference**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Answer (score 11):

`^` used at the beginning of a character range, or negative lookahead/lookbehind assertions.

```
>>> re.match('[^f]', 'foo')
>>> re.match('[^f]', 'bar')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f8b102ad6b0>
>>> re.match('(?!foo)...', 'foo')
>>> re.match('(?!foo)...', 'bar')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f8b0fe70780>
```

Comment: Do you have to use `?!` in the last 2 examples or can you just use `!` by itself? What does `?` do there?

Comment: Python needs the `?` in order to tell that it's an extension. Other regex engines may have their own rules.

Comment: @Click: It's pretty standard. http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html, also most regexp engine manuals say the same thing.