# RegEx function failing to remove illegal chars?

Tags: javascript, regex, nightwatch.js

As far as I can tell, my RegEx is correct and the replace method should be doing it's thing. Looking at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925738/which-regular-expression-operator-means-dont-match-this-character) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682905/how-to-negate-regex), it seems I am using the same, or a very very similar, RegEx pattern, and they are accepted answers.

So I'm thinking perhaps I'm doing something wrong with the .replace method?

Ideally, the RegEx should match anything **not** contained in the character class, meaning anything that is not: a-z, 0-9, '-', '.', and '_'. I read that there is no need to escape special characters within character classes (except '[', ']', and '-') so I have only escaped the hyphen.

Any help is much appreciated. To clarify; passing the below function this string:

`'_;<!--Invalid--!"s"' null'` should return 
`____--invalid--____null`.

```
function nameSafe(name) {
  var rgxIllegalChars = /^[^a-z0-9\-._]+$/;
  name = name.toLowerCase();
  return name.replace(rgxIllegalChars, '_');
}
```

Edit: Solved, see accepted answer for information. Finished function:

```
function nameSafe(name) {
  var rgxIllegalChars = /[^a-z0-9\-._]+/gi;
  return name.replace(rgxIllegalChars, '_');
}
```

I added some debugging output to my function to try and catch the before and after, and somewhat foolishly forgot that .replace doesn't actually replace the original string. So I was doing this:

```
console.log(name);
name.replace(rgxIllegalChars, '_');
console.log(name);
return name;
```

My apologies - if you're also having trouble, never forget to check your absolute basics (like I did) - does the method your using return a new object, or replace the existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regular expression `^` means `assert position at start of the string` and `$` means `assert position at end of the string` once you remove these two it will give you your expected result.

I have created a sample on Regex101.com for you https://regex101.com/r/xF7vA8/3, click on Substitution button to see the result.

[image]

Comment: This certainly seems to work at Regex101.com - and I noticed you added the g tag (which I should also) - but my results, strangely, are still the same before and after the function. I'm worried now it's something to do with async

Comment: Can you post complete code? May be we can help you better after having a look at complete problem.

Comment: while you are at it, add the `i` flag and remove the `toLowerCase()` stuff

Comment: Is the + important? I thought it was needed (to match any single char within the character class any number of times) but perhaps the -g flag negates the need for this in JS?

Comment: I think you don't need + as it will change meaning of your expression have a look at https://regex101.com/r/xF7vA8/4 and pay attention to 'Substitution' result by adding and removing +, when you add it, it does explain saying `Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]`

Comment: I did see that, and noticed it still matches what I need it to. Interestingly, adding a + will replace multiple instances of illegal chars with a single '_', whereas leaving it out ensures there is one '_' per matched illegal char in the string. Not sure about the performance benefits!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove anchors:

```
function nameSafe(name) {
  var rgxIllegalChars = /[^a-z0-9\-._]+/;
  name = name.toLowerCase();
  return name.replace(rgxIllegalChars, '_');
}
```

---

Edit:

```js
var name = "'_;<!--Invalid--!\"s\"' null'";
var rgxIllegalChars = /[^a-z0-9\-._]+/g;
name = name.toLowerCase();
alert(name.replace(rgxIllegalChars, '_'));
```

Note this line `var rgxIllegalChars = /[^a-z0-9\-._]+/g;`

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer! I tried that, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I also logged the result before and after, to ensure it was actually being called - input and output is the same :(

Comment: Your code 100% works in my browser, running through dev console. For some weird reason, I'm still not getting the expected result in my output... maybe this thing runs deep :(

Comment: Updated OP to shed light on the issue. Embarrassing... removing anchors did it, really, I just got schloppy. Thanks for your time