# Not in regular expression not working

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make a regular expression that matches a line when it has a number followed by a ok word.

Eg:

```
10 ok
```

But if there is a number and nok after the ok word, then it should not match.
Eg:

```
10 ok    2 nok
```

I am using the following regular expression to achieve this:

```
[0-9]+\s+ok\s+(?!([0-9]+\s+nok))
```

I am using the 4th answer from [Which regular expression operator means 'Don't' match this character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925738/which-regular-expression-operator-means-dont-match-this-character) to generate a `not` functionality in my regex.

Here is my code:

```
import re

prog=re.compile('[0-9]+\s+ok\s+(?!([0-9]+\s+nok))')
result=prog.search('108601                  ABC_kill                            11 ok  3 nok        95m   25_KLPO   casdas5  dus41  fdd     tm500  sdfsd1010_1014             2m    2016-02-11 02:30:50  2016-02-11 08:53:59')

print (result)
```

But my pattern still matches with a line that contains `nok`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\d+\s+ok(?!\s+\d+\s+nok)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJ3xC4/1)

Important is to keep `\s+` inside the negative lookahead to fail the match for 2nd case.

Comment: But can you explain, why it should be inside the negative lookahead?

Comment: If it is not inside the lookahead then `\s+` is not greedy enough to match all the spaces after `ok` and lookahead will fail since there is a space before next number. Besides `10 ok` doesn't even have a space after `ok`

Comment: In PCRE you can make `\s` greedy by using `\d+\s+ok\s*+(?!\d+\s+nok)` but that regex won't work with Python

Answer (score 1):

```
s='10 ok  2 nok'
      # ^---- two spaces here
re.search(r'[0-9]+\s+ok\s+(?![0-9]+\s+nok)', s)
```

will succeed. Let's see what happens:

`[0-9]+\s+ok\s+` matches `'10 ok  '` (with the two spaces), but after `(?![0-9]+\s+nok)` fails.

At this point, the regex engine uses the backtracking mechanism and `\s+` gives back a character (the last space), then `[0-9]+\s+ok\s+` matches `'10 ok '` (only one space) and `(?![0-9]+\s+nok)` succeeds with `' 2 nok'`

To avoid the backtracking, you can emulate an atomic group `(?>...)` (that forbids backtracking once closed) with `(?=(...))\1` *(a lookaround is naturally atomic)*:

```
(?=([0-9]+\s+ok\s+))\1(?![0-9]+\s+nok)
```