# Regex how to match everything that doesn't follow the format with 3 digits followed by a dash then 4 digits?

Tags: regex

`\d{3}-\d{4}`
This one matches something like `123-4567`

So I change it to `^(?!(\d{3}-\d{4}))`. But it doesn't match anything.

I got a list of phone numbers like

```
123-4567
NOW-4-WAX
12 345 67 89
```

I would like to match anything except the format `xxx-xxxx` where `x` is a digit.

Comment: You could try [\d{3}-\d{4}] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925738/which-regular-expression-operator-means-dont-match-this-character

Comment: Can you share samples of matching strings? How is your string composed? (is it always made up of numbers? Does a dash always occur in it?)

Comment: @lemon OK, I modify my post with few examples. `xxx-xxxx` should be the correct numbers. I'd to find all other wired data.

Comment: Add `.*` after your regex. Does it work for you? (`^(?!(\d{3}-\d{4})).*`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `.*` to the end of your regex, it should match any line that does not start with a phone number in the 123-4567 format.

**Demo on RegExr:** [`^(?!(\d{3}-\d{4})).*$`](https://regexr.com/6pclv)

It's worth noting that if you have anything in your input file that is not a phone number at all, this will match those too.